# When choosing Apex servers it shows no packet loss yet I get packet loss every other match

Tags: apex-legends

I got back to Apex after a year-long break, and all of a sudden, I started having menu freezes -> some parts of the menu were grey and inaccessible, and currencies had stuck animations. Along with this problem, I started having a terrible packet loss, making the game pretty much unplayable. What is weird about this is that usually, after I restart the game, the first one or two matches work just fine, and then I get menu freeze or packet loss in the next match, and I have to reset the game again.

What I tried: flushing DNS, changing the Apex server from Frankfurt to Amsterdam (ping < 50), changing a bunch of Apex game settings, and creating an exclusion for Apex in my antivirus networking (which is also managing the firewall).

I believe that the issue is related to the Apex servers even though it always shows 0% packet loss when selecting one because it gets worse during the main times such as 8-10pm yet I have no idea how to fix it.

Do you have any hints on what else could I try to fix this issue?